# Hibernate retrieve records

Tags: hibernate

Is it possible to retrieve table records  from database in hibernate without saving the same records using session object??( in simple I have inserted records manually in table from mysql workbench , now how do I retrieve the same table records in hibernate)

Comment: Usually you can retrieve any single record if you know the primary key, regardeless how it was inserted (assuming of course the new insertion was also committed and visible to other transactions)

Comment: Thanks for replying ..but this is not my query ..I know by get and load using primary key , I have used query API to fetch the records from  table , but the problem is query API is fetching only those rows which I have inserted through session object through save method , it's not fetching the rows which I have inserted manually through mysql workbench

Comment: After you have committed the insertion you have to start a new transaction within your session otherwise the new record is not seen (except you have changed the default isolation level to dirty read)

Comment: OK I will check this point ...thank you